# How can I rank a table in postgresql and then find the rank of a specific row?

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgresql table

```
cubing=# SELECT * FROM times;
 count |  name   |  time  
-------+---------+--------
     4 | sean    |  32.97
     5 | Austin  |  15.64
     6 | Kirk    | 117.02
```

I retrieve all from it with `SELECT * FROM times ORDER BY time ASC`. But now I want to give the user the option to search for a specific value (say, WHERE name = Austin) and have it tell them what rank they are in the table. Right now, I have `SELECT name,time, RANK () OVER ( ORDER BY time ASC) rank_number FROM times`. From how I understand it, that is giving me the rank of the entire table. I would like the rank, name, and time of who I am searching for. I am afraid if I added a where clause to my last SELECT statement with the name Austin, it would only find where the name equals Austin and rank those, rather than the rank of Austin in the rest of the table.

thanks for reading

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the behavior you want here is to first rank your current data, then query it with some `WHERE` filter:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY time) rank_number
    FROM times
)

SELECT count, name, time
FROM cte
WHERE name = 'Austin';
```

The point here is that at the time we do a query searching for `Austin`, the ranks for each row in your original table have already been generated.

**Edit:**

If you're running this query from an application, it would probably be best to avoid CTE syntax.  Instead, just inline the CTE as a subquery:

```sql
SELECT count, name, time, rank_number
FROM
(
    SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY time) rank_number
    FROM times
) t
WHERE name = 'Austin';
```

Comment: I have a node.js file I'm searching through my database with. So could I use `const temp = await pool.query('SELECT count,name,time FROM (WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY time) rank_number FROM times)) WHERE name=''Austin');`?